# QGIS Layout: Locking the scale of loaded map even though the location changes

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Curently I have made some templates of layouts where there just needs to be set the map theme and the location that can be panned to a "favorite" location. The problem annoyance is of course when you pan to that location, we have reset the scale back to what it was intended. Now my Question is there somewhere an option to "lock" the scale so that even though we pan to this favorite location, the scale does not change?

This favorite location is more meant to "center" the map on a project area, making the project area be in the center of the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QGIS Layouts try to be smart at adjusting parameters when other elements change, including map canvas view (if relevant), page size, etc. Usually that's good, but sometimes the wrong parameter is adjusted.

The way to truly lock something is to set it to the desired fixed value as a data-defined override. In the below, if I merely type `144448` into the Scale field, QGIS may change it if I modify the extents, page size, etc.  But I've clicked the icon to the right of the field, which was a grey list, and set it to be the fixed value `144448` in the expression editor. Now it will stay put. Of course, you could put a more complicated, actually data-driven expression there if you wanted.

[image: Scale setting]

Comment: Thank you that is good enough for now.